# Not sure where " Serialization of 'PDOStatement'" is happening?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Ive tried to create a basic login script using PHP and a SQL database. On submit, it goes all the way through to `<script>window.alert("Successfully Signed In!");</script>`  then it throws me an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'PDOStatement' is not allowed in [no active file]:0 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in [no active file] on line 0

This is my login script, not very long....

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


//Verifying Username is associated with an account 


//Verifying Password is correct with the username 
$pverify = "SELECT `password` FROM users WHERE username = :username";
        $pass = $conn->prepare($pverify);
        $pass->execute();
        $pass->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $checkpass = $pass->fetchColumn();



        
        
            
        if (password_verify($password, $checkpass)){
        
            //Get user ranking
            
            
                echo'<script>window.alert("Sucessfully Signed In!")</script>';

            }else{
            echo'<script>window.alert("Your password is Incorrect!");</script>';
            }
        
    
}   

?>
```

I have a Header included into the page bringing some extra code with it:

````
<?php

@session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = "guest";
$_SESSION['rank'] = "1";

function is_session_started()
{
    if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
        if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
            return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
            return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

// Example

?>

<?php

$userrank = $_SESSION['user'];
$getrank = "SELECT `rank` FROM users WHERE username = :username";
$rank = $conn->prepare($getrank);
$rank->bindValue(':username',$userrank);
$rank->execute();
$rank = $rank->fetchColumn();
?>```
````

Comment: On a side note: `if ($ucount = NULL)` and `if ($ucount = "1")`: you compare using `==`, not `=`

Comment: You are also calling `bindValue` _after_ `execute`, it should be the other way around

Comment: How are you storing passwords in your database, exactly?

Comment: Why are you doing the second query before checking `$ucount`?

Comment: And `$ucount` will never be `NULL`, it will always be a number.

Comment: Don't do two queries. Just do the query to fetch the password. If the username isn't found, `$checkpass` will be `NULL`.

Comment: FYI, it's generally considered poor security to distinguish between invalid username and invalid password.

Comment: passing the password through `$pass = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_ARGON2I );` on a create page, the running a db query `$add = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, ip, email, phone, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
      $addu = $conn->prepare($add);
      $addu->execute([$user, $pass, $ip, $email, $phone, $created]);`

Also thanks for the tips, and info, still learning ALOT :)

Comment: The error you got would happen if you try to use `$uverify` or `$pass` as a string. I don't see anything in this code that would do that, it may be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: It's also happening after the alert, so you must be sending something to the server after receiving this response.

Comment: I'm skeptical of the before and after concept. I've seen `window.alert()` block the UI from painting so it might still be before, you just can't quick tell except through view source. To the OP, after making all of the changes suggested so far, does it still cause the same error?

Comment: Updated code still gives same error

Comment: @ChrisHaas if you want, https://ghostbin.co/paste/7nrdspj is the entire page